# firebase phone authentication not working after .apk released in play store even after I have updated sha1 in firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, signed-apk

Firebase phone authentication not working after `.apk` released in play store even after I have updated `sha1` in firebase console after that I have generated google-`services.json` again and updated json file in android studio project.

**There was many other sha1 was also present in firebase console project setting** should I delete them before generating new google-services.json

Comment: Did your problem solved ? I have the same issue.

Comment: yes my problem was solved with the answer given below

Comment: @UsamaAhmed You should mark the answer as accepted as a way of thanking the person who answered

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you upload an app to the play store then the play store creates a new certificate called "App signing certificate". This will contain the SHA1 certificate that you require. It can be found at:

Select App -> Under Release -> Setup -> App Sigining on your play console. Copy SHA1 and paste it in your Go to Console -> Select Project -> Project Settings -> Under General Tab -> Under Your Apps -> Select App -> Add SHA1 fingerprint.