# Firebase auth not work when use Proguard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, proguard, android-proguard

This is the structure of my project

[image]

I use Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Phone Auth. The app works fine but when i set

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Firebase not send to me the SMS code for the auth.
I used this proguard-rules

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class persistence.** {
  *;
}

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** 
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

what did I do wrong?

This is my gradle

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: This proguard file looks correct to me for firebase excludes - but are you sure it is being read? Do you see that it is skipping these files in your build output? Can you include relevant lines from your build gradle file?

Comment: "Do you see that it is skipping these files in your build output?" How can i check this?
I added the buildTypes of gradle

Comment: this might not a proguard problem, did you check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772115/firebase-phone-authentication-not-working-after-apk-released-in-play-store-even

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!!!