# Firebase phone verified OTP some number are verified, other are not verified after received OTP in PHONE, When I uploading flutter app to Play store,

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I have made a flutter app with firebase with phone-based OTP verification, it is working fine in debug mode and release APK. But after uploading to the play store then there is a problem, **the phone is received an OTP message But when it enters the OTP number in the application SOME ARE VERIFIED AND OTHER ARE NOT VERIFIED as is showing the wrong OTP  but I enter the exact number**. and also I have updated the **google-service.json** file, I have added SHA - 1 and SHA - 256 keys from the play console to firebase project settings, still, it's not working.

My questions: Is there something else I should look at? I've also double-checked the google-services.json with no success

[enter image description here][1]

[image]

Comment: Can you check if this links help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47050790/15774177 ?

Comment: thanks for response but it is not working